# Different templates for different categories/Pages

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-templates

knows anyone an article I can implement a template-system in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application?

Like many other websites, my own has many different categories and for each should use there own template.

The color circle is the template (like musictemplate_layout.cshtml) and ContentPlaceHolder123 has always the same content.

[image]

Best regards, 
Patrik

Comment: What do you exactly want?

Comment: For example, if I click at a category link "Xbox 360", the page will become a green layout. Category Ps3 become a blue layout and so on

Comment: Easily you can create different Templates in your MVC application and use them in such pages.you can also create it dynamically by setting 'Layout' at the top of each page.

Comment: But how can I realize it? Perhaps I will display the same content in a different template

Comment: done. I hope my example can help you

Answer (score 1):

Create different Views as your specific templates like bellow:
[image]

Use different layouts by defining at the top of each page like bellow:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout1.cshtml";
}
```

Also, you can have more levels of Layouts, according to your interface plans. You can use layouts dynamically by different factors, like UserAgent or ... by Placing string variable in front of 'Layout' for more adoptable or intelligent results.

Comment: Hey, thank you for comment.
What exactly is _Common? I just found _ViewStart in my project folder with the definition of Layout. 
I'm thinking that your way is the correct, but how can I manipulate the layout variable? Somehow, it must indeed be possible to read the category out of the url /Category1/Book123 or read it out of the database..